# Pimcore - How to check object is updated or not?

Tags: object, pimcore

I am working on pimcore cms.
I want to check whether my object is updated or not.

Scenario is I am integrating pimcore cms with other cms where all data comes in pimcore from that another cms.
So I am able to get all the data in pimcore as well.

But once I update any object from pimcore I need some flag or something which tell other cms that this object is updated.

So after that other cms will not synchronize that particular object to pimcore

**So how to check whether the object is updated or not?**

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new check box with a parameter "not visibility" and set the flag to true if field has been updated.

Comment: Do you mean in my object class i need to add field ? after that where this field will be stored ?i mean in db ? how can  i get this field is updated or not

Comment: If you mean object, you say pimcore class object(https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Objects/Object_Classes/index.html) or pimcore editables(https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Documents/Editables/index.html)?

Comment: Yes i am talking about pimcore object class , i have created Product  class and it have more than 15 fields

Comment: Yes, you need to add new field to your class. If you add field like "flag", you can access to this field by getters, for example: `$test = YourClass::getById(objectId); ` The "test" variable holds all your fields

Comment: Yes thats correct but that i can access in pimcore cms . but the same field i need to access in another cms where i can identify this object is updated. so when i synchronized csv file that particular object not needs to sync

Comment: I got a little confused. If you want to get object from another CMS you need to use REST API. If there is something else it needs a broader description

Comment: Yes i will used rest api !!! i dont need object !! i need that flag field of object in another cms. so other cms got to know this object is updated

Answer (score 0):

You could use Symfony Events in Pimcore. Whenever you save an object in Pimcore you could send the updated data (fields) to your other cms afertwards.